# symfony migration User deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, mariadb-10.3

```
alialhoumadi@Develtos-MacBook-Pro kantoorplanning % php bin/console make:migration
```

> [critical] Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" In ExceptionConverter.php line 101:

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known In Exception.php line 28:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known  In Driver.php line 33:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known  In Driver.php line 33:

> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known  make:migration

> 2023-10-02T13:09:54+00:00 [info] User Deprecated: Relying on a fallback connection used to determine the database platform while connecting to a non-existing database is deprecated. Either use an existing database name in connection parameters or omit the database name if the platform and the server configuration allow that. (Connection.php:458 called by Connection.php:410, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5707, package doctrine/dbal)
> alialhoumadi@Develtos-MacBook-Pro kantoorplanning %

hi my name is Ali ive had this error when i try to migrate. im using symfony 5 with mariadb 10.3 in a multi container using docker and i tried everything i cant migrate anything ive made sure my db works like 7 times and ive updated composer everything is up to dat there is no syntax errors or any misspelling. please excuse me if my message is bad or if i need to provide more info this is my first time on here.

Comment: Sounds like the app can't reach the database

Comment: are you sure the containers can connect with each other and run the command from within your container. Other options can be to check your .env connection url. Can you share your .env file config?

Comment: yes im sorry here is my .env file 

DATABASE_URL=mysql://symfony:symfony@mariadb:3306/symfony

APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=

Comment: What if you run php bin/console doctrine:database:create ? Just to check if you can connect. If not, check if you set port 3306:3306 in your docker-compose.yml

Comment: i ran it and i couldnt create one i got the following error: wodby@php.container:/var/www/html $ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database `symfony` for connection named default
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'symfony'; database exists
wodby@php.container:/var/www/html $ 

i checked the ports once again but they were correct and since the db exists in the error im guessing the issue isnt with the database itself perhaps could it haver something to do with my docker container?